# HTML form not showing success message after successful user registration

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me why my success message is not showing on the HTML form after successfully registering a new user? I can see from my database that the user has been registered, however, instead of getting a "success message" the page reloads and no message is shown. Here are the HTML and the JavaScript codes am using. And also it is throwing this error and I have no idea on how to solve it **"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"**.
Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});

function newUser() {

  // object
  var user = new Object();
  var error;

  // user inputs
  user.fname = $('#fname').val();
  user.lname = $('#lname').val();
  user.username = $('#username').val();
  user.usertype = $('#usertype').val();
  user.email = $('#email').val();
  user.phoneno = $('#phoneno').val();
  user.pswd1 = $('#pswd1').val();
  user.pswd2 = $('#pswd2').val();

  error = true;
  if (error == true) {

    $
      .ajax({
        url: 'AddUser',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',

        success: function(data) {

          if (data.message == "Registered") {
            alert("Registered!");

            $("#message").empty();
            $("#message").append(
              $('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">' +
                '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
                '<i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="text-align: center">' +
                data.message +
                '</i></div>'));

            $('html,body').scrollTop(0);

          } else {
            $("#message").empty();
            $("#message").append(
              $('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">' +
                '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
                '<i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="text-align: center">' +
                data.message +
                '</i></div>'));

            $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
          }
        },

        error: function(data, status, err) {
          alert("error: " + data + " status: " + status + " er:" + err);
        }

      });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registration Page</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Pooled Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />

  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    addEventListener("load", function() {
      setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
    }, false);

    function hideURLbar() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="web/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="web/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/morris.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Graph CSS -->
  <link href="web/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- //jQuery -->

  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,500,300,100italic,100,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- lined-icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/icon-font.min.css" type='text/css' />
  <!-- //lined-icons -->


  <!-- These are my own scripts -->
  <script src="js/registration.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="message" style="width: 20vw;margin-left: 24vw;"></div>
  <div class="main-wthree">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sin-w3-agile">
        <h2>New User Registration</h2>

        <form action="#" method="post">

          <div class="username">
            <span class="username">First name:</span> <input type="text" name="fname" class="name" id="fname" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="username">
            <span class="username">Last name:</span> <input type="text" name="lname" class="name" id="lname" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="username">
            <span class="username">Username:</span> <input type="text" name="name" class="name" id="username" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="username">
            <span class="username">User type:</span>
            <select name="usertype" id="usertype" required="">
              <option></option>
              <option value=1>Admin</option>
              <option value=2>Normal</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <br>
          </div>

          <div class="username">
            <span class="username">Email:</span> <input type="text" name="email" class="name" id="email" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="username">
            <span class="username">Phone number:</span> <input type="tel" name="phoneno" class="name" id="phoneno" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="password-agileits">
            <span class="username">Password:</span> <input type="password" name="password" class="password" id="pswd1" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="password-agileits">
            <span class="username">Confirm Password:</span> <input type="password" name="password" id="pswd2" class="password" placeholder="" required="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="login-w3">
            <input type="submit" class="login" id="registerUser" onclick="newUser()" value="Register">
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does `js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js` exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists. I have it

Comment: No need for "error = true;  if (error == true)" - it will always take this path.  No need to complicate the code when trying to debug.  The "$" error is because jquery is not being loaded.  Check your file location and make sure it is jquery.  Until you get this, nothing else will work.

Comment: @GeekDiva - Double check that you have it. Replace that URL with this CDN `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js` and tell us if you still see `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: David this is what is basically did and it didnt work. <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> @CFP Support I do have the jquery and it seems to have no error in it. The code still not working.

Comment: @CFP Support, I got the query to work but still I can't get the success message to display on the form.

Comment: Update your answer to show your latest changes.  Also add what is in AddUser (typically that would be a .php file......) as your JS relies on what comes back from that - and it relies on what is sent from the ajax call.  Everything has to 'line up' before you can get your success message (actually, that is the least important thing in all this! :)